# Preferences - How to change all TextView colors?

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, preferences

as title says i wanna to change textView of all text in app when clicked on background color. I did it for background color , i just need to add row to edit all text COLOR .. how i can do it here?
I need to add text color to line 129

SEE [image: IMAGE FOR MORE]

Answer (score 0):

You can change color of `TextView` as

`textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));`

Comment: You didn't read my post nor you saw my code image. that doesn't works in sharedpreferences 
" else if (preferences.getString("color", "0").equals("2")) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);"

This is code for background colour- I need code to change all characters on main activity from BLACK to WHITE...

Comment: To change color of all textView you have
to Create a color attribute and store it in SharedPreferences and associate your full app to that color. 
In your Activity class parse yourColor in each textView.